# Disable ALL hints in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

As per the image:

[image]

Intellij adds `: String` to my code, I don't want Intellij to add random text to my code.  Is there any way to disable this completely?

I've found some settings that allow my to uncheck "Foreground" and "Background", but the weird grey box still remains after unchecking these:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is missing a bit of context, but this looks like it is a ["type mismatch" hint](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2019/07/02/functional-highlighting-for-functional-programming/#type-ascription-to-type-ascription). The best way to remove it is to fix the type error ;)

If you would like to disable this way of highlighting type errors, go to
Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Scala | Editor | Type mismatch display and select "Highlight expression"

[image]

Comment: Just a simple red underline is soooo much better.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the foreground/background colors (and having the box virtually exist, but in an invisible way) I think you actually want to disable the hints altogether. To do this open the project settings and go to `Editor > General > Appearance`. Disable the `Show function return type hints (Scala)` checkbox. Optionally, disable other hints if you have them enabled and they bother you.

[image: hints]

Comment: THanks. I already have those check boxes disabled.  Could it be a bug in Intellij?

Comment: @samthebest It's possible. You can check their issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues